# Проблема с плюсованием, я даже не знаю как это объяснить

Tags: javascript, html, таймер

В коде четко и ясно указано, что функция Plus выполняется каждую секунду, добавляя 1 к переменной Test.
В моем случае функция выполняется огромное количество раз в секунду, что приводит к зависанию страницы, в чем может быть проблема? Помогите!!!

Первый раз сталкиваюсь с подобным, до этого много работал с таймером setInterval и т.д.[image: И это всего за пару минут]

```
<script>
    Test = 0;
    function Plus(){
        Test++;
        console.log("Test = " + Test);
        setInterval(Plus, 1000);
    }
    Plus();
</script>
```

Comment: Вынесите setInterval за пределы функции, она вызывает себя же и создает новые и новые интервалы

Comment: @Gleb испанский стыд, дай бог вам здоровья, вы не представляете как много времени я потратил на поиск проблемы

Answer (score 2):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) запускает повторяющийся таймер, который будет сам запускаться через равные интервалы.

Внутри `Plus` запускается `setInterval`, который каждый раз запускает `Plus`, в котором запускается новый `setInterval`. Таким образом количество запущенных интервалов постоянно увеличивается.

Для решения нужно либо запускать `Plus` отдельно в интервале

```
Test = 0;
function Plus(){
    Test++;
    console.log("Test = " + Test);
}
Plus();
setInterval(Plus, 1000);
```

Либо использовать [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), который запускается только один раз:

```
Test = 0;
function Plus(){
    Test++;
    console.log("Test = " + Test);
    setTimeout(Plus, 1000);
}
Plus();
```

Answer (score 0):

а зачем вы сначала вызываете plus, а потом еще раз в setInterval?
Так ведь тоже работает:

```
Test = 0;
function Plus(){
    Test++;
    console.log("Test = " + Test);
}
setInterval(Plus, 1000);
```